# GitHub - find out who removed user from an organization?

Tags: github, admin, rights

I work in a company that uses GitHub enterprise.
Someone removed a user from an Organization. Is there a way for me, or anyone, to find out who was it that removed the user?

I imagine there is perhaps a log of user actions somewhere (that shows things like "user added" "user removed"), but I can't see anything of the sort.

Help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually an audit log for GitHub enterprise which you can export to track the events related to the user deletion.

> The audit log allows organization admins to quickly review the actions
>   performed by members of your organization. It includes details such as
>   who performed the action, what the action was, and when it was
>   performed.

https://help.github.com/articles/reviewing-the-audit-log-for-your-organization/

Comment: Thank you so very much sir or madam. It was this exactly I needed.

Comment: What if someone removed you from an organization? In this case since you are not a member (and so not admin) you can't use Audit Log.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be in the audit log.

> The audit log allows organization admins to quickly review the actions performed by members of your organization. It includes details such as who performed the action, what the action was, and when it was performed.

Here is a link with more information about the audit log.
https://help.github.com/articles/reviewing-the-audit-log-for-your-organization/#searching-the-audit-log

I hope that this is of any help